# Application of GIS in geology

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, geology

I am a student of geophysics and I am studying geographic information systems (ArcGIS) and we have been given a project. As I do not have much information about GIS capabilities can you please suggest me a topic for my project which is related to geology or geophysics?

For example, my fellow classmates are doing project on they creating a tectonic map which will also show where earthquake occurs.

Comment: As an easy intro take a look [here](http://www.esri.com/industries/natural-resources) to get an overview. And [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/tutorials/) is a good introductory link on how to make a webmap focused on volcanic activity.

Comment: something I'd love to understand through GIS capabilities is how fault systems work, especially those in wrenching environments. I have no idea how to implement that, so I think it can be a good starting project, very difficult though.